# Indexing criteria for elasticsearch

Tags: twitter, elasticsearch

I am working with twitter streaming api. and am a little confused about deciding the criteria for indexing the data. Right now I have a single index that contains all the tweets in one doc_type and users in another doc type.

Is it the best way to go about storing them or should i create a new doc type for every category (category can be decided on basis of hashtag and tweet content)

What should be the best approach to storing such data?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

At first, the answer to your question is that this very much depends on your use case. What is your application doing? What do you do with the tweets? How many categories do you plan to have?

I'd in general, however, go for a solution where you use the same index and the same `doc_type` for all tweets. This allows you to build queries and aggregations over all your tweets without thinking about the different types of categories. It also allows you to add new categories easily without having to change your queries.

If you want to do some classification of the tweets you could add a category field to the tweet document stored in elasticsearch. You can then use this category field to implement your specific application logic.

If your category names have spaces or punctuation marks don't forget to define the category field as `not_analyzed`. Otherwise it will be broken up in parts.